# Javascript: How to get the text value of drop event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I wondered how to get the text value of a drop event. It seems to be an easy question but surprisingly I can't find an answer that works.

Demo below

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dropbox" contenteditable="true" id="dropbox">
</div>

<style>
#dropbox{
width:400px;
height:60px;
background-color: #87cefa;
}
</style>

<script>
$('#dropbox').on('drop', function(e) {

console.log(e.dataTransfer); //first try
console.log(e.getData('Text'));  //second try

});     
</script>
```

Comment: what do you mean by "the text value of a drop event" ? Events don't have text value.

Comment: get the value of the text which user dropped , I mean.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you almost had is, but since you are using [jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/), the original event used in [Mozilla's example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/ondrop#Example) (for example) needs to be accessed as follows:

```
console.log(e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData("text"));
```

The above link also shows how to prevent the browser from following the text as if it were a url (by disabling the default behavior for both 'dragover' **and** 'drop'). You also need to make sure that there is space in the div for you to be able to drop something there (below, I just set the style to make the div take up the entire viewport). Putting this all together using jquery:

```
<script>
$('#dropbox')
    .css('width', '100%')
    .css('height', '100vh')
    .on('dragover', function(e) {
        console.log('in the box');
        e.preventDefault();
    })
    .on('drop', function(e) {
        console.log(e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData("text"));
        e.preventDefault();
    });  
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

First, it's a good idea to wrap your DOM-manipulating code in a ready call, so that the page is ready before you start manipulating it. See this link for more details: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Then, this code should work:

```
var dropstr;
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#dropbox').on('drop', function(e) {
        e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.items[0].getAsString(function(str)
        {
            dropstr=str; 
        })

    });
});
```

The dataTransfer API is a bit involved, but you can find more details here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer

Comment: You don't need document.ready if the DOM elements are loaded before the script.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't use the variable str outside  GetAssString, demo below. How to fix this? Thanks again. `$('.topic_container').on('drop', function(e) {

     e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.items[0].getAsString(function(str){
      dropstr=str;
     });
     
     alert(dropstr);
});  `Where  I tired to move the string inside a global variable `dropstr ` in order to use the string for other use, but it returns undefined.

Comment: @DinoMyte Good point. Answer updated.

I also updated my answer to show how to assign the string to a global variable.